# Allow user deletion but keep references to them

Tags: django, user-accounts

What is the standard way of allowing a user to delete their account from your website without removing any references to them, so that others can still see them?

For example, how does Stack Overflow do it? I assume that, when you delete your account, your posts and answers aren't deleted as well? So how do they manage it?

Comment: I guess the standard is to *soft-delete* a user: add a `deleted_at` attribute that defaults to null and set it to a date when the user is deleted. Of course, you have to update some other queries in your application to hide deleted users (and perhaps their content).

Comment: How would this fit with users that actually want their data to be deleted? ie. from a GDPR request?

Answer (score 0):

The standard why to do this in django is to deactivate the user by setting the `is_active` attribute on the `User` object to `False`.

See the link in the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active

Comment: This makes sense, I think. Then I just need to ensure that I don't show links to the inactive users anywhere. I'm not sure how it sits though when a user requests that their data actually be deleted (as in the case of GDPR for example).

Comment: When a user requests for their data to actually be deleted, then you can delete the user object and everything related to it. But inactive makes sense for most cases

Comment: I guess that was my question really. How would you go about deleting user data? Obviously, some objects in the database will have links to the user data you're going to delete, and you probably wouldn't want to delete them all. So with SO, for instance, they wouldn't want to delete all their potentially useful posts.

Comment: Then that really comes down to how you structure the foreign keys to the user objects. You could use `on_delete=models.SETNULL`, on foreign keys to the user object that you want to be nullified when you delete the user object (like a post), and treat a null user as a deleted user. For other objects that you want to delete when the user is deleted set `on_delete=models.CASCASE`

Comment: Yup, I think that makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the help.